# Find a positive simple s-t Path on a Graph is NP-Complete?

Tags: algorithm, graph, path-finding, np-complete

I'm trying to find something on the literature to help me to solve this problem:

Given a graph with non negative edge weights, find a simple s-t positive path of any size, i.e., a path that goes from **s** to **t** with length greater than 0. I was trying to use dijkstra algorithm to find a positive shortest path by avoiding relax the edges that have cost zero, but this is wrong. I don't want to believe that this problem is NP-Complete =/. Sometimes it seems to be NP-Complete, because there may be a case where the only positive path is the longest path. But this is such a specific case. I think that on this kind of instance the longest path problem is polynomially solvable.

Can someone help me identifying this problem or showing that it is NP-Complete ?

Observations: The only requirement is to be some positive path (not necessarily the lowest or longest). In case of multiple positive paths it can be anyone. In case of non existence of such path, the algorithm should flag that the graph has no positive path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is NP-complete even with only one single edge having value 1, and all the others having value 0.  Reduce from **Two Directed Paths**:

**Two Directed Paths**
**Input:** A directed graph G and two pairs of vertices (s1, t1) and (s2, t2)
**Output:** Two vertex-disjoint paths, one from s1 to t1 and from from s2 to t2.

Create a new instance with all edges having weight 0, and create an edge from t1 to s2 with weight 1.

Comment: Hello Pål. Shouldn't the proof be in an inverse way? To show that a Problem Y is NP-Complete is necessary to show that some other problem X (a known NP-COMPLETE problem) reduces to Y. Proving that Y reduces to X is also desirable, but it is not sufficient. For example, I can prove that Y='sorting problem' reduces to a graph instance for the X = 'traveling salesman problem', but the contrary does not apply.

Comment: @Felipe yes, but that's what we're doing here. Y is your problem, X is Two Directed Paths (2DP). We start with an instance of 2DP, and turn it into an instance of Y (your problem). Now, the intuition is that if there's a fast algorithm for Y, then there's a fast algorithm for 2DP, which would imply P=NP.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra's algorithm produces an answer in polynomial time (so in P rather than NP) and provides a shortest path between any 2 points on the graph.

Please refer to [Dijkstra's Algorithm Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) for further details.

You don't really need any more proof.

I'm not quite sure how "relax the edges that have cost 0" has any impact on this question at all.